# Not able to add new created sub site under “Sites” header in quick launch in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a tool to create root site and the tool also creates few sub-sites in it. Now I want to show these sub-sites in the Quick Launch of the root site in `SharePoint 2010`.

These should come under the header “Sites” in Quick Launch. By default `SharePoint 2010` does not have “Sites” header in quick launch. The header “Sites” is seen only when new sub site is created with checking the option to display it on quick launch from the Browser.  I have two scenarios to discuss.

First case (header “Sites” already exists in quick launch)
When I create a new sub site, it adds the new site under “Sites” header, which is working fine.

Second case (header “Sites ” does not exists in quick launch)
In this case, the Quick Lunch of root site does not have any sub-sites – it means the quick lunch does not have “Sites” header. When, the tool will create sub-sites in this root site, I wanted to have “Sites” header in the Quick lunch and also display the sub-sites under “Sites” header.

I have tried various approaches to achieve this but could not success.
I have tried to add “Sites” header in the Quick Lunch using the code given below and I could able to show the sub-sites under this “Sites” header. But again if I add sub-site from the Browser, the another “Sites” header is seen and this sub-site is seen under this “Sites” header. So now the quick lunch has two “Sites” header – which I wanted to avoid.

I wanted to have to have just single “Sites” header and all sub-sub-sites under that header.

I used this code to add “Sites” header in Quick Lunch

```
quickLaunchSitesNode = web.ParentWeb.Navigation.GetNodeById(1026);

If (quickLaunchSitesNode == null)

            {
                SPNavigationNode newNode = new SPNavigationNode("Sites", parentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx?ShowSites=1", true);
                quickLaunchSitesNode = parentWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsFirst(newNode);
                quickLaunchSitesNode.Update();
                parentWeb.Update();
            }
```

Is there any method to add newly created sub-sites under the header “Sites” in quick launch in `SharePoint 2010` programmatic-ally?